# C# UDP Listener Thread -- Don't Burn CPU with while(true)?

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, udp

With the following code, is there a better way to set up a UDP listen than a `while(true)` with `Thread.Sleep(10)`?

```
    public void Start()
    {
        socket.Bind(ip);
        while (true)
        {
            data = new byte[1024];
            receivedDataLength = socket.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);
            raw = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, receivedDataLength);
            row = new LogRow(raw);
            //Console.WriteLine(row.ClientIp);
            row_queue.Enqueue(row);
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReceiveFrom` is blocking. Thread will be suspended until data arrives. Unless `Socket` is in non-blocking mode.

Comment: You should add that because `ReceiveFrom` is blocking, there's no need for the `Sleep`.

Comment: Ah okay, it must be my insert thread that is burning the CPU. Thanks I will drop the `sleep`.

Comment: @Kyle Brandt♦ yes, `Spleep` is excessive. Run Application in debug and when burning starts pause debug and check each non-sleaping thread.